# What is the difference between @observable and @published

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Until Polymer 0.10.1 the `@published` annotation created an attribute on the Polymer element where it was declared.
This changed with Polymer 0.11.0. Since then `@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)` is needed to make the fields value available as an attribute.

It seems that since this update `@published` has just the same effect as `@observable`. Am I missing something?

Comment: You've got to have `@published` before you can get to `@tenured`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `@published` attribute still allows you to use the value as an attribute itself in the HTML declaratively. That is you can still do:

```
<my-element myprop="{{hello}}"></my-element>
```

The change is that accessing the values procedurally via the `attributes` property, then you must include `@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)`. (This does not seem to be the case if you're interactive with the CustomTag class directly.

Needs `@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)`:

```dart
var x = querySelector('x-foo');
x.bar = "hi";
// ...
print(x.attributes["bar"]);
```

This also needs `@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)`:

```css
/* CSS */
x-foo[bar="hi"] { background-color: blue; }
```

This does not:

```dart
XFoo x = querySelector('x-foo');
x.bar = "hi";
...
print(x.bar);
```

This was inferred from the discussion group for [New Polymer Release 0.12.0](https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/d/msg/web/DTTQGHl_Wjo/8STQFbLCM9QJ)

Comment: Great! Thanks for the link. I guess I need to read this discussion again. Interacting with the CustomTag class directly doesn't need any annotation, an existing field is enough.

Comment: What do you think, wouldn't it be more convenient when `reflect: true` would be default and the argument annotation would be used for the other case `@PublishedProperty(reflect: false)`. I guess this is used the way it is because `reflect: true` is also used in Polymer.js. I didn't need a published attribute with `reflect: false` since this change was introduced.

Comment: Personally I rarely use 'attributes' to interact with my components, just two way binding declaratively. So I've not needed the `@PublishedProperty(reflect: true)` at all.